# How to base labels of facet_wrap on a column that isn't the wrapping column

Tags: r, ggplot2

For example,

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(
  Id = c(1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3),
  x = c(1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 4),
  y = c(1, 2, 1.5, 4, 5, 4.5),
  Label = c("mean: 1.5", "mean: 1.5", "mean: 1.5", "mean: 4.5", "mean: 4.5", "mean: 4.5")
)
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y))+facet_wrap(~Id)+geom_point()
```

[image]

I would like to base the labels on the "Label" column.  In this case, I can't simply do `ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y))+facet_wrap(~Label)+geom_point()` because Ids 1 and 2 happen to have the same label.

I tried `ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y))+facet_wrap(~Id, labeller = labeller(setNames(df$Id, df$Label)))+geom_point()` to no avail.

Comment: In the data frame you posted, Ids 1 and 2 don't have the same label.

Comment: @Lyngbakr oops.  Fixed.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's kind of a dumb hack:

```
dumb_label <- function(df){
  list(c("mean: 1.5", "mean: 1.5", "mean: 4.5"))
}
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y))+facet_wrap(~Id,labeller = dumb_label)+geom_point()
```

This is probably a better approach:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
  facet_wrap(~Id,labeller = labeller(Id = c('1' = "mean: 1.5",'2' = "mean: 1.5",'3' = "mean: 4.5"))) + 
  geom_point()
```